# format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument has type 'int'

Tags: c

```
 if (answer == 'Y') {

    int a, u, l;
    printf("How many numbers do you need?\n");
    scanf("%d", a);
```

The program crashes after this line. What should I be using instead of "%d"?

```
    printf("Specify the lower bound of the range:");
    scanf("%d", l);

    printf("Specify the upper bound of the range:");
    scanf("%d", u);

    for(c = 1;c <= a ;c++) {
        n = rand() %(u - l) + 1;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any C tutorial on using `scanf()` should explain this clearly.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

`scanf()` needs as argument an address where he can store the information.

`a` is the name of the variable, while `&a` is the address of memory that contains that variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address of the variable, because `scanf()` will store the value in it.

The program crashes because `scanf()` is dereferencing an `int` which is not even yet initialized both things cause undefined behavior.

In fact, all these are undefined behavior and all occur in that single `scanf()` call

1. Dereferencing an invalid pointer
2. Passing the incorrect types for given format specifiers.
3. Reading from uninitialized variables.

To pass the address use the `&` address of operator

```
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
    // Proceed with `a' and use it
} else {
    // Bad input, do not use `a'
}
```

In this case, the warning is not an error because `int` is in principle convertible to a pointer, but the behavior is undefined if you try to reference such type, and also the pointer size might be too big for `int` to store it.

This warning is very severe, ignoring it will never result in good behavior because it involves treating a value that is unlikely to be a pointer value as if it was, this normally would lead to the program crashing.

In general, you should only ignore a warning if you **REALLY** know what you're doing. And almost never, you do someting on purpose that would trigger a warning, although there are situations where it might be legit.

As a beginner (*I know that you are a beginner simply because you are using `scanf()`*), you MUST NOT ignore a warning.

Also, even if your text book examples never check the return value of `scanf()` you should. Not doing so, and specially when you haven't initialized the variables yet will probably invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Pass address of the variable in scanf as shown below:

```
 if (answer == 'Y') {
    int a, u, l;

    printf("How many numbers do you need?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Specify the lower bound of the range:");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    printf("Specify the upper bound of the range:");
    scanf("%d", &u);

    for(int c = 1;c <= a ;c++) {
        n = rand() %(u - l) + l;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

}
```